# How to check that state for a oauth2 azure logon

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We do the following

1. get a authorization code from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` providing a state
2. wait for a callback to the `redirect_url`, this will obviously get a unrealted state (and session)
3. redeem the authorization code to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token" to get a bearer access code for MS graph

how in any of these steps can we establish reasonable trust that the tokes are reliabele? Multiple sessions don´t share any knowledge at our side (like a session cookie or anything) so can we trust the bearer access code?

Comment: You validate the JWT token i.e. access/ID token - google 'JWT validation Microsoft AD' and you should get plenty of results. A JWT token is stateless, it doesn't need a session - all information needed to verify it is contained within. Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validate-tokens

Answer (score 0):

Created an Azure AD application:

[image]

To get **authorization code** I used below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenanID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
code:code
```

[image]

> how in any of these steps can we establish reasonable trust that the tokes are reliabele? Multiple sessions don´t share any knowledge at our side (like a session cookie or anything) so can we trust the bearer access code?

The authorization code expires after few minutes and can only be used once. Hence even if the code is intercepted, someone would not be able to access your application using it.

When I tried to re-use the authorization code, I got the error like below:

[image]

And additionally, as your making use of `tenant` endpoint or sign-in URL, only authorized users inside the organization will be able to access to the app, reducing the chance of unauthorized access.

- As you are making use of HTTPS encryption, application will be more secured.
- The state parameter is used to prevent attacks.

I agree with @*ermiya-eskandary*, A JWT token is stateless and does not require a session because it already has all the data required to verify it.

Note that: The Microsoft Graph API or other resources access token is not meant to be validated. The tokens generated for your application must be only validated.

**References:**

[Azure security baseline for Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/aad-security-baseline?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Farchitecture%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Farchitecture%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)

[Secure your Azure AD identity infrastructure - Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/steps-secure-identity)